# .NET localization tool - free or full-featured trial

Tags: .net, localization, translation, globalization

I'm looking for a tool to automate the process of localizing one software product. Is there any free, or trial version with no limits other than time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been looking at [Google Translation Toolkit](http://translate.google.com/toolkit?hl=en&layout=1&eotf=1) for my job, but no opinion yet.

Also [TMX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_Memory_eXchange) is an open standard in this area.